# Current in a branch containing both resistor inductor?

Tags: circuit-analysis, transient

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ5u7o.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
There is a switch in the circuit which has been closed recently so the circuit is now in transient state and we are applying KCL at node 1.
 Also we cannot use Laplace transform.
Is there a method for this?

WE have to apply KCL at NODE1 , How can we write the expression for current in the branch containing capacitor and inductor? As we have for left and right branches i.e $$ (V_1 - 1)/100 $$ and $$ (V_1 - 0)/100$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express the series L/C/R branch as a complex impedance - either via Laplace transfom: \$\small Z(s)=R+sL+\frac{1}{sC}\$, or the equivalent in the frequency domain: \$\small Z(j\omega)=R+j\omega L+\frac{1}{j\omega C}\$. As the source is a direct voltage, Laplace is the way to go.

Comment: One thing that I not mentioned is that the circuit is in the transient state, a switch in the circuit is closed recently.@Chu

Comment: See updated answer - use the Laplace transform for transient analysis (unless you want to go down the differential equation route!)

Comment: We have DC source @Chu

Comment: Actually I'm looking for a method other than Laplace, is there anyone?@Chu

Comment: Differential equation

Comment: But impedence is not defined for DC powered circuits.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Differential equation or Laplace can be used for transient analysis

Comment: Could you please write a complete equation for KCL at node assuming the circuit in transient state@Chu

Comment: No. That's your job - update your question when you've gone as far as you can with the analysis. We give advice, but don't do homework on this website.

Comment: Actually thats not my home work I have extracted this part from a complicated circuit while doing transient analysis we have not studied laplace yet so I'm looking for alternative method